# Как выбрать одно из двух значений для одной переменной?

Tags: python

```
healthPerc = 100 #как этой переменной принимать разные значения,в зависимости от        условий выполненых раннее...
count = 0

while (count < 1):
    cell_health = random.randint(0, 100)
    newHealth = count + cell_health
    count = count + 1
    print('You lost - {0} health.\nYou health: {1}'.format(newHealth, (healthPerc -     newHealth)))
if (healthPerc - newHealth) > 50:
    print('Do you want continue?')
if (healthPerc - newHealth) < 50:
    print('You loose!!!')`
```

Переменной `healthPerc` может быть присвоено одно из 2-х значений. Подскажите, как мне использовать одно из них в зависимости от выбора? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про какой выбор вы говорите? Здесь не указаны условия, в зависимости от которых будет меняться значение healthPerc. Как пример можно использовать следующее:

```
healthPerc = 50 if is_half_health else 100
```

Либо такой вариант:

```
if full_health:
    healthPerc = 100
elif is_half_health:
    healthPerc = 50
elif damage > 50:
    healthPerc = 25
else:
    healthPerc = 0
```

Опишите более подробно часть "Переменной healthPerc может быть присвоенно одно из 2-х значений", тогда можно будет подсказать, что именно вам надо (точнее - как надо).

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись. Более подробно: Условия которые меняют значения healthPerc это ввод цифры 1 или 2 в диалоговом окне, типа выбор"персонажа игры", у одного(цифра 1) healthPerc равен 100 у другого(цифра 2) 150.Приведенный выше код должен симулировать бой,тоесть отнимать какое-то количество жизней у выбраного персонажа. Перед боем выбирается или персонаж-1 у которого  healthPerc-100 или персонаж-2 у которого healthPerc-150. Как отнимать 'жизни' понятно, а вот как в 'код' выше, в переменую healthPerc  подставлять разные значения (в зависимости от выбора персонажа 100 или 150) не понятно

Comment: Если поможете разобраться, я буду очень благодарен. Возможно, нужно сделать вообще все по-другому.

Comment: @Oposum, не знаю, как вы получаете ответ из диалогового окна, поэтому покажу на примере простого input:

    used_person = int(input("first or second (1 or 2)?\n"))
    healthPerc = 150 if (used_person == 2) else 100

Ошибки не обрабатываю, т.к. сейчас не их рассматриваем. Неправильный выбор не обрабатываю по той же причине.

Comment: Ворон спасибо большое, теперь работает! Ответ не из диалогового окна, я ошибся, а через input:
Спасибо за поддержку еще раз.